# Stray end tag "form"

Tags: html

I am getting error `Stray end tag "form"` in below HTML code.

```html
<section class="login-section reg-section card">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5 ">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="reg-left">
          <h3>Account Login Details</h3>
          <form method="POST" action="">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email Address*</label>
              <input value="" type="email" name="reg_email" class="form-control " placeholder="Email" id="login_email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password*</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control " placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password*</label>
              <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control " placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
            </div>
        </div>


        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
        </form>
</section>
```

[image]

Why I am getting this error ? Why the tags are red ? How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra closing `div` tag at line 123, as highlighted by your editor in your screenshot.

The red in the screenshots are indicating issues with your html structure. The `form` and `div` tags need to have associated closing tags that allow them to wrap their contents. As is, you are closing a `div` that doesn't have an associated "opening" tag within its direct parent.

Delete the extra closing `div` tag to fix the current errors, then you'll probably need to close the remaining `div` tags within your `section`.

Answer (score 1):

You close the div that contains the form and try to close the form afterward.

try closing the div after you close the form.

the correct way of how your form should look like:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email Address*</label>
    <input value="" type="email" name="reg_email" class="form-control " placeholder="Email" id="login_email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password*</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control " placeholder="Password" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password*</label>
      <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control " placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, look at your indentation - you have :

```
    <form>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
</div>
</form>
```

So your core problem is that that red-coloured end-div tag does not match an opening div tag, so the solution is to just delete it.

In addition, you are not closing your input tags;  have them finish with  />.

Comment: Thanks @racraman. I need to use in this way `<form>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
    <div>
</form>
    </div>` . Thanks.